# Elisp function throws error only when called while init.el is open in buffer

Tags: debugging, emacs, anki

I am using Emacs, and wrote a custom function in init.el to make it easier for me to create [Anki flashcards](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) upon press of a keybind. This specific function is used to retrieve two values (using [Anki-Connect](https://github.com/FooSoft/anki-connect)) and let me choose them from a list (the function is based on behaviour found in [anki-editor](https://github.com/louietan/anki-editor).

In order to do that, I declared a few variables outside the function, so that I can later use their values in a org-capture-template. They are set to nil at the start because I check somewhere else if they have already been set and otherwise call the below function first.

---

My solution works, but only as long as init.el (or Emacs.org, from which it is compiled by tangle) is closed. If I call the function while init.el is open, I get the following error: "Wrong number of arguments: (3 . 3), 2" - I do not understand why that happens.

How can I fix this problem?

My code looks like this:

```el
(defvar my-anki-deck nil)
(defvar my-anki-notetype nil)
(defvar my-anki-fields nil)

(defun my-anki-set-deck-and-notetype ()
  (interactive)
  (setq my-anki-deck (completing-read "Choose a deck: "
                                      (sort (anki-editor-deck-names)
                                            #'string-lessp)))
  (setq my-anki-notetype (completing-read "Choose a note type: "
                                          (sort (anki-editor-note-types)
                                                #'string-lessp)))
  (setq my-anki-fields (progn
                         (anki-editor--anki-connect-invoke-result
                          "modelFieldNames"
                          `((modelName . ,my-anki-notetype))))))
```

Below is the detailed error message (I tried to format it nicely, this is the best I was able to do):

1. Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (3 . 3) 2)
2. request--curl-callback(# "finished\n")
3. anki-editor--anki-connect-invoke("deckNames")
4. anki-editor-deck-names()
5. (sort (anki-editor-deck-names) #'string-lessp)
6. (completing-read "Choose a deck: " (sort (anki-editor-deck-names) #'string-lessp))
7. (setq my-anki-deck (completing-read "Choose a deck: " (sort (anki-editor-deck-names) #'string-lessp)))
8. my-anki-set-deck-and-notetype()
9. funcall-interactively(my-anki-set-deck-and-notetype)
10. command-execute(my-anki-set-deck-and-notetype record)
11. counsel-M-x-action("my-anki-set-deck-and-notetype")
12. ivy-call()
13. ivy-read("M-x " [evil-collection-magit-toggle-text-minor-mode table--measure-max-width vc-src-responsible-p lsp:omnisharp-run-tests-in-class-request-column nexti tramp-completion-handle-file-name-all-completions term-do-line-wrapping lsp-watch-kind? speedbar-check-vc-this-line access-label curr-btn magit-revision-filter-files-on-follow treemacs-dom-node->set-position! calcFunc-rgrade term-handle-exit &error rng-parse-validate-file magit-xref-insert-button speedbar-file-regexp gnus-agent-group-covered-p evil-collection-org-maps edebug-mode-on-hook message-expand-name-databases C-i autoload-find-file c-make-ml-string-opener-re-function gnus-try-warping-via-registry magit-list-modified-modules pullreq_label:pullreq gnus-server-compact-server :odt-styles-file gdb-thread-number :mac org-table-get-range vc-bzr-shelve-menu rng-match-infer-start-tag-namespace Above nnimap-status-message gnus-summary-limit-to-marks treemacs--get-label-of nnmail-message-id-cache-file treemacs-python-executable article-fill-long-lines smime-buffer-as-string-region lsp:set-file-operation-pattern-options? diredfl-symlink Parchment c-default-value-sentence-end rg-elisp-font-lock-keywords posframe-poshandler-frame-bottom-left-corner ...] :predicate #f(compiled-function (sym) #<bytecode -0x11c32b217e0c370d>) :require-match t :history counsel-M-x-history :action counsel-M-x-action :keymap (keymap (67108908 . counsel--info-lookup-symbol) (67108910 . counsel-find-symbol)) :initial-input nil :caller counsel-M-x)
14. counsel-M-x()
15. funcall-interactively(counsel-M-x)
16. command-execute(counsel-M-x)

Comment: Bisect your init file, to find the culprit. If the problem exists and you don't understand the part of your code that causes it, post only that code, i.e., a bare, reduced init file, and provide a recipe to repro the problem.

Comment: I've fixed some lisp formatting problems, and also re-formatted to keep lines under 80 columns so others can read your code more easily.  Note that your `progn` is redundant in the last line.

Comment: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and then show the resulting error backtrace in your question.

Comment: I have now added the error message to the opening question!

Comment: It looks like the library which defines `anki-editor--anki-connect-invoke` and the library which defines `request--curl-callback` are not in sync with one another.  Evidentially `request--curl-callback` takes 3 arguments, but `anki-editor--anki-connect-invoke` is only passing 2.  Try updating either or both of those libraries/packages, and you should probably raise a bug report for the "anki" one, as I'm guessing it needs to declare a dependency on some particular version(s) of the other library.

Comment: In your bug report, point out that `request--curl-callback` is name-spaced as an *internal-use* function (that's what the double-hyphen means), and therefore anki should not be calling it at all, as maintainers may make breaking changes to internal-use functions at any time.  There will be some public API function to use instead.